# Insert a default value in textarea, upon creation

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have a text area. I need to have a default value. The `"value"` property doesn't seem to work. The textarea is just empty (I get no errors). But when I inspect it with Firebug, the value is there.

Is it possible to have a default value somehow?

I tried to create a textarea in pure html (not using ExtJS), and there it works fine with a default value.

I know this can be achieved using JavaScript, but this should be the last possibility.

```
  xtype: 'textareafield',
  value: 'The default value',     
  padding: 3,
  minWidth: 700,
  id: 'areaID',   
  readOnly: true
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1nqn), please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the emptyText property which acts like placeholder text. I would use that in conjunction with value to achieve your desired results.